# Xamarin forms android MasterDetailPage after opening a few pages the images do not appear

Tags: android, xamarin

i have a problem with forms android.
I'm using a MasterDetailPage and after opening a few pages the images do not appear in the new pages.
Instead with ios it works.

Comment: Please improve your question,  add code and things you tried to debug it. maybe you are doing too much on your main thread.

Comment: and if i relly use to much the main thread how can i solve it?

Comment: Run your app in release mode (Debug/mono uses more resources), implement async tasks. A lot of questions already asked about that, look at them for solutions.